# How to reconnect a connected webRTC peer to another peer?

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

I have my client A and client B connected to each other. However I wish to disconnect my client A and connect it to client C. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible. Why not create a new PeerConnection and negotiate the session?

You could maybe find a hacky way to make it work with a ICE + DTLS Restart. It would be undefined behavior/not supported by all clients.